# Feature request: Show hide button for animated gifs

Tags: feature-request, images

When asking questions about concurency and race conditions it can be usefull to include an animated gif to demonstrate the problem: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/287999/start-a-service-when-the-first-client-connects-and-stopping-it-when-the-last-cli?noredirect=1#comment594766_287999 . Unfortunately, animations can be distracting to the reader or to the person who is trying to write a comment. It would be nice to add a "hide/show" or "show/hide" button for animated gifs so that the user could hide the animations when they were not looking at them.

Comment: your question still seems to be getting down votes, even with images covered by spoilers and with explanation about it. This is probably because it's still not convenient to read. Comparing to how it was received neutrally [with images replaced to links](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/287999/2), you might want to reconsider this approach. And, no matter if you prefer showing images or links to these, consider scaling them down, as in current shape these appear to render rather poorly (granted, when I view images outside of the post, it looks a bit better but still)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a feature that can be used.

The spoiler tag ">!" works on images too.

Example:

> [image]

One can then just mouse over to see the image.

I've taken the liberty of adding them to your original post. You get big white blocks but they work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work well, especially if I add a comment before the image telling people to mouse over it to see it :) .

Comment: The image is still downloaded with page load.  The issue with the animated gifs in [the question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/287999/) in question is that they are about 17 ***megabytes*** of data.  Hiding them with a spoiler tag does not make the hit to my data cap on my phone any smaller (it just makes it more annoying to read). They failed uploading to imgur because of the 2 megabyte max size.